# append multiple files in descending order in dos cmd

Tags: sorting, append

I have some files with names 93112.txt, 93111.txt, 93110.txt etc.
I want to put them into a single combined file such that
the largest number file goes in first, then the next smaller
...and finally the smallest.

I need a short DOS command to do it.Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`dir /b | sort /r > sorted.txt`

- `dir /b` prints only the item names in a directory.
- `|` pipes the output of `dir /b` to `sort`.
- `sort /r` preforms a reverse (descending) [natural sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_sort_order) of the item names.
- `> sorted.txt` redirects the standard output of `sort` to a text file (`sorted.txt`).

**Notes**

- Unlike `sort`, `dir` outputs item names in [lexographical order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order), which can affect items with numbers in their names (e.g. `1, 2, 12, 22` is sorted as `1, 12, 2, 22`).
- For your use case, it is likely undesirable to use `dir /b` by itself (without `sort`).
- `dir /b` includes all file and subdirectory names in a directory.
- Any output text file (e.g. `sorted.txt`) will be created before `dir /b` is executed.
- To avoid having e.g. `sorted.txt` included in `sorted.txt`, run these commands outside the directory you wish to sort and specify a path to the directory in `dir /b` (i.e. use `dir /b "C:\path\to\folder"` in place of `dir /b`).
- You can use `.` as a shorthand reference to the current directory to avoid typing e.g. `C:\long\path\to\current\directory`.
- More information on Windows [dir](https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) and [sort](https://ss64.com/nt/sort.html) commands.

---

> I need to append the files in the descending order of names.

You will need a second command to loop through your files and concatenate them after you have produced your list of sorted names (e.g. `sorted.txt`). As an example:

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %i IN (sorted.txt) DO type "C:\path\to\folder\%i" >> appended_items.txt
```

For batch files, use `%%` rather than `%` (which is what you would use at the command line). Note that `>>` is used with the [type](https://ss64.com/nt/type.html) command to append to an existing file (e.g. `appended_items.txt`).

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response!. I just need to go one step further... I need to append the files in the descending order of names. How should I modify the above script?

Comment: Not a problem. =) You would need a second command to process e.g. `sorted.txt`. I have updated my answer.